# local JMX connection

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

Using the reference to [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/jmx_connections.html) .
I am trying to Make an Explicit local `JMX Connection`.
After executing

```
 java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 - Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -jar   test.jar command
```

I am  trying  to make make `JMX` connection. But when I tried to connect with `localhost` and `port 3333`,

I got **error saying** `cannot connect to localhost:3333 using service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi/://localhost:3333/jmxrmi`.
I tried according to document but i can not figure out what is the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can't tell without codes. try to `telnet localhost 3333`

Comment: As oracle document says The target application should be run on same  host as Java VisualVM but was started by a different user than the one who started Java VisualVM.But,in my case i am making log in as suppose X user.And i am starting both VisualVM and target application.How it is possible to run VisualVM by one user and target application by another user on the same localhost?

Comment: What's the complete exception and stack trace if any?